# I want to count values in name column if there are only in sequence form in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, gaps-and-islands

```
create table #t (Id int, Name nvarchar(max))    

insert into #t 
values (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'ABC'), (3, 'BBB'), (4, 'BBB'),  
       (5, 'BBB'), (6, 'BBB'), (7, 'CCC'), (8, 'BBB'),  
       (9, 'BBB'), (10, 'ABC')
```

I want to count values in name column if there are only in sequence form
how I get this result as shown in table below:

```
| Name | Repetition |   
('ABC'),    2
('ABC'),    2
('BBB'),    4
('BBB'),    4
('BBB'),    4
('BBB'),    4
('CCC'),    1
('BBB'),    2
('BBB'),    2
('ABC'),    1
```

Comment: Please remove the C#, jquery and MVC tags if they aren’t relevant to the Q&A.

Comment: Why do you want `BBB` listed 4 times? Why not just once?

Comment: Sir Its our Requiremnet When Row Has Same Name In  Sequence On that Time I want to Count It And Give There  COunt Value in every Rows

Comment: @EnvisionInc. Please check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try gaps and islands type approach of counting consecutive rows like below

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/YGGBI13965)**</kbd>

```
select 
    Name, 
    Repetition= count(1) over(  partition by r,Name )
from 
(
    select 
    *, 
    r=id-row_number() over(partition by Name order by Id) 
    from #t
 ) t
order by id
```

Comment: Thanks but Please check .. wrong result found.
create table #t (Id int, Name nvarchar(max))    
insert into #t values   
(1, 'ABC'), 
(2, 'ABC'), 
(3, 'BBB'), 
(4, 'BBB'), 
(5, 'BBB'), 
(6, 'BBB'), 
(7, 'CCC'), 
(8, 'BBB'), 
(9, 'BBB'),  
(10,'ABC'),
(11,'ABC'),
(12,'ABC'),
(13,'ABC'),
(14,'CCC'),
(15,'ABC'),
(16,'ABC'),
(17,'CCC'),
(18,'GGG'),
(19,'FFF'),
(20,'GGG'),
(21,'AAA')

select 
    Name, 
    Repetition= count(1) over( partition by r )
from 
(
    select 
    *, 
    r=id-row_number() over(partition by Name order by Id) 
    from #t
 ) t
order by id

Comment: Please check 17,18,19,20 row

Comment: @EnvisionInc. Thank you for pointing that out; answer updated and corrected

Answer (score 3):

Try this multiple cte solution:

```
;with name_change as (
  select *, case when name=lag(name, 1) over (order by id) then 0 else 1 end as indicator 
  from t
), name_group as (
  select name, sum(indicator) over (order by id) as g 
  from name_change
)
select name, count(name) over (partition by g) from name_group
```

<sub>Not sure about the efficiency though, but I think it gives what you need...</sub>

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d24bf1/8)

Comment: thanks, we r working in sql server 2008 r2 and lag function is not available . please provide alternative query.

we want same result that u provided previous query